# how to deallocate a data structure

Tags: c

i have allocated the following structure,using dataset_creator function, and i want to free this structure(dataset, i maen) with all of its components.
would you help me please??

```
struct dataset{
  char *title;
  struct linked_data *head;
  struct dataset *next;
  struct attribute **hash_table;
};

struct dataset* dataset_creator(char *name,struct attribute *expressions,struct query *query){


struct dataset *ds;                    //"ds" is the abbreviation of word "dataset"
//struct attribute **hash_table;
//struct linked_data *data;
struct attribute *current_attribute;
//int i;
int j;
int index;


ds=(struct dataset*)malloc(sizeof(struct dataset));
if(ds==NULL){
    printf("failed memory allocation request\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
ds->next=NULL;
ds->title=(char*)calloc((strlen(name)+1),sizeof(char));
strcpy(ds->title,name);


ds->head=(linked_data*)malloc(sizeof(struct linked_data));
if(ds->head==NULL){
    printf("failed memory allocation request\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
ds->head->next=NULL;


ds->hash_table=(attribute**)malloc(MAX_NUM_OF_ATTRS * sizeof(attribute*));
if(ds->hash_table==NULL){
    printf("failed memory allocation request\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
for(j=0;j<MAX_NUM_OF_ATTRS;j++)
    ds->hash_table[j]=NULL;
for(j=0;j<MAX_NUM_OF_ATTRS;j++){
    index=hash(expressions[j].name,MAX_NUM_OF_ATTRS);
    if(ds->hash_table[j]==NULL){
        ds->hash_table[index]=(struct attribute*)malloc(sizeof(struct attribute));
        ds->hash_table[index]->next=NULL;
    }
    else{
        current_attribute=ds->hash_table[index]->next;
        while(current_attribute->next != NULL){
            current_attribute=current_attribute->next;
        }
        current_attribute->next=(struct attribute*)malloc(sizeof(struct attribute));
        current_attribute->next->next=NULL;
    }
}


 return ds;
}
```

sorry for the grammatical mistakes;
note:that is not the whole code;

Comment: Standard warning: Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()`/ `calloc()`.

Comment: One `free()` for each `malloc()` or `calloc()`.

Comment: Consider this style `ds->hash_table = malloc(MAX_NUM_OF_ATTRS * sizeof *(ds->hash_table));`  Cleaner, easier to maintain, less change to mis-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the order:

```
1. free(ds->hash_table[index]); /* Free all the single pointers memory first in a loop*/
2. free(ds->hash_table);
3. free(ds->head);
4. free(ds->title):
5. free(ds);
```

You have another allocation for your structure `current_attribute` so free that memory also

```
free(current_attribute->next);
```

Answer (score 1):

For every pointer in your data structure, you must use `free`, and also for the structure itself. But make sure the pointers you are freeing aren't used somewhere else. Also, if you have nested pointers (e.g. `struct attribute **hash_table`), you have to take care of the pointers inside the pointers as well.